# What value do I declare on the title transfer if I make an even trade?

Tags: united-states, car, sales-tax

I am considering trading a car to my friend in exchange for some livestock (of similar value). The car is worth $9000, and the livestock is worth closer to $11,000. What do I put in the sale price on the title transfer?

Comment: What state is this?

Comment: Well, the IRS says its "fair market value", so it would be $9k to them...but I don't know if applies to what you should put on the title for your state, so I don't think this would be a proper answer: https://www.irs.gov/uac/four-things-to-know-about-bartering-1

Comment: Consider the states of Utah, Wyoming, and Colorado for this question as the vehicle could be titled in any of those states.

Comment: What is unclear to me is not the fair market value of the car, but whether trade-in rules apply.

Comment: If your car is a Bronco, Mustang, etc, you might try claiming this is a 1031 like-kind exchange :-}}

Answer (score 2):

The buyer settled on Utah for the state to title it in, and in that state, they specifically prohibit any trade consideration for non-vehicle trades, so I wrote up a bill of sale and put the sale price as $9000 to reflect fair market value.